# Simple closed economy problem

Tags: macroeconomics

Consider a simple closed economy model where **Y = C + I + G**, consumption is given by the function **C = 100 + 0.5 (Y - T)**, investment is **I = 50**, government purchases are **G = 20**, and the government’s 
budget is balanced.

How do I work out what tax is, to work out the amount of autonomous spending? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Figure out what tax is equivalent to from 'budget balance' and autonomous spending is the spending not related income, so think what the spending level is when wealth is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your equations, you can find

$$Y = C + 50 + 20 \implies Y = C + 70$$

You can then substitute $Y$ for its equal into your other equation

$$C = 100 + 0.5(C + 70 - T)$$

Finally, given a balanced buget, you know that $G = T$, which should be enough for you to solve for $C$.